# unrecognized escape sequence ,please resolve it

Tags: c#

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
namespace UnitTestProject1
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http:\www.facebook.com");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(@"http:\www.facebook.com");`

Comment: not excuting.....

Comment: Are you getting the same error? You can use this `driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http:\\www.facebook.com");`

Comment: `GoToUrl("http://facebook.com");`

Comment: You could just google this. Just use @ before strings that contain escape characters such as "\" .

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.facebook.com");
```

Notice the double `//` in the URL

Another way is:

```
 driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(@"http:/www.facebook.com");
```

Comment: Who on earth is using backslashes for URLs?

Comment: @UweKeim Clearly, Chakri Y is. Seriously though, I do see it commonly enough not to be surprised by it any more.

Comment: @UweKeim I mentioned @ only first. but it didnt work for him. Then only i suggested \\

Comment: how to run the test case? iam going to the method name right click and run tests----is that correct?

Comment: @ChakriY Yes! By the way, have your problem got solved?

Comment: From C# perspective you have done the right thing about escaping the backslash character in a string i.e. using either two back slashes or using `@` sign at the beginning of the string but ideally URLs always use forward slashes instead e.g. `http://www.facebook.com`. If you use the correct URL format them you won't need any of the escape sequences. Web browsers are usually smart enough to replace back slash with forward slash but programs might fail if the corresponding class in your framework isn't doing any such URL handling.